# Loop to return all Woocommerce product tags in alphabetical order

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

i am trying to make a loop in WordPress for woocommerce theme to get out all product tags in alphabetical order
in a simple way "heading with A below it all tags starts with A letter etc."
i am using the code but its return null

```
<?php
            $tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
$tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

$html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag- 
>slug}'>";
$html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a [`WP_Term_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/) with the Woocommerce product tag custom taxonomy, to get all related terms alphabetically by letter:

```
$taxonomy  = 'product_tag';
$tags_html = [];
$tquery    = new WP_Term_Query( array(
    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
    'orderby'      => 'name',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'   => false,
) );

// 1st Loop: Go through each term and format it
foreach($tquery->get_terms() as $term){
    $link   = get_term_link( $term->term_id, $taxonomy );
    $letter = $term->slug[0];
    // Set alphabetically by letter each product tag formatted html (with the class, the link and the count (optionally)
    $tags_html[$letter][] = '<a class="'.$term->slug.'" href="'.$link.'">'.$term->name.'&nbsp;('.$term->count.')'.'</a>';
}

echo '<div class="product_tags">';
// 2nd Loop: Display all formatted product tags grouped by letter alphabetically
foreach( $tags_html as $letter => $values ){
    echo '<div class="letter-'.$letter.'">Letter '.strtoupper($letter).':&nbsp;'.implode(' - ', $values).'</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Tested and work.

---

**Edit related to your comment**

To limit the number tags for each letter, you will use:

```
$taxonomy  = 'product_tag';
$tags_html = [];
$tquery    = new WP_Term_Query( array(
    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
    'orderby'      => 'name',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'   => false,
) );

// 1st Loop: Go through each term and format it
foreach($tquery->get_terms() as $term){
    $link   = get_term_link( $term->term_id, $taxonomy );
    $letter = $term->slug[0];

    // Get the existing array keys for a letter
    $keys   = isset($tags_html[$letter]) ? array_keys($tags_html[$letter]) : array();
    // Limit to 5 items by letter
    if( sizeof($keys) < 5 ){
        // Set alphabetically by letter each product tag formatted html (with the class, the link and the count (optionally)
        $tags_html[$letter][] = '<a class="'.$term->slug.'" href="'.$link.'">'.$term->name.'&nbsp;('.$term->count.')'.'</a>';
    }
}

echo '<div class="product_tags">';
// 2nd Loop: Display all formatted product tags grouped by letter alphabetically
foreach( $tags_html as $letter => $values ){
    echo '<div class="letter-'.$letter.'">Letter '.strtoupper($letter).':&nbsp;'.implode(' - ', $values).'</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Not tested…

Comment: thank you so much it's working with me
but i need now to filter output to 1 for every letter
when i put 'number' => '1' in agrs return only letter A and stops

Comment: @MinaAmir I have made an update for this at the end of my answer. It's untested. try it and let me know if it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

The [`get_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) function retrieves an array of objects for each term in the `post_tag` taxonomy. WooCommerce products don't use `post_tag`, they use the `product_tag` taxonomy.

The function you want to use is [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/):

```
$terms = get_terms(
    array( 
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
    ) 
);
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
if($terms){
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_tag' );
        $html .= "<a href='" . $term_link . "' title='" . $term->name . " Tag' class='" . $term->slug . "'>" . $term->name . "</a>";
    }
}
$html .= "</div>";
echo $html;
```

If you need then in alphabetical order, check out [`get_terms_orderby()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_orderby/)